# Eigenvalues of $B+(B- I)C(B- I)$ with $B$ idempotent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a matrix $\bf A$ which satisfies

$$ \bf A = \bf B + (\bf B - \bf I)\bf C (\bf B - \bf I), $$

where $\bf I$ is the identity matrix, $\bf B$ is symmetric and idempotent, and $\bf C$ is symmetric with the modulus of its eigenvalues less than or equal to $1$.

> I want to show that all eigenvalues of $\bf A$ have modulus less than or equal to $1$.

This might not be true, but I have not been able to find a counter-example. This fact might be helpful:

$$ \bf A\bf B = \bf B\bf A=\bf B. $$

Comment: You need to impose some constraint on the size of $C$, otherwise this is not true in general when $C$ is sufficiently large. Counterexample: $B=0$ and $C=2I$.

Comment: You are right, I edited the question accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B$ is symmetric and idempotent, i.e. it is an orthogonal projection. So, by a change of orthonormal basis, we may assume that $B=0_{k\times k}\oplus I_{n-k}$. Hence (with respect to this basis) $A=C_k\oplus I_{n-k}$, where $C_k$ is the leading principal submatrix of $C$. Now the spectral radius of $C_k$ is bounded above by the spectral radius of $C$, which by assumption is at most $1$. Therefore $\rho(A)\le1$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you get $A=C_k\oplus I_{n-k}$? I thought I understood it but am having difficulties working it out explicitly. What I have attempted is to premultiply the equation by $P$ and postmultiply it by $P^\top$, where $P$ is such that $PBP^\top=0_{k\times k}\oplus I_{n-k}$. But I can't replicate the result this way.

Comment: @mzp If you perform a change of basis, $A$ and $C$ have to undergo the same change. The $C_k$ here is a submatrix of the **new** $C$ after such change, not of the original $C$. More specifically, we let $B_{\text{new}}=PBP^T=0\oplus I,\  C_{\text{new}}=PCP^T=\pmatrix{C_k&\ast\\ \ast&\ast}$ and $A_{\text{new}}=PAP^T$. As $A,B,C$ all undergo the same change of basis, the relation $A_{\text{new}}=B_{\text{new}}+(B_{\text{new}}-I)C_{\text{new}}(B_{\text{new}}-I)$ is preserved.